# MYSQL - GROUP BY and COUNT query

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

I have a database containing rows like this

```
title          category
-----------------------
super widget      1
ultimate widget   1
regular widget    1
happy widget      2
sad widget        2
ugly widget       3
pretty widget     3
```

using the query below, I get a nice list of all rows with a title like "widget" and a count of how many are in each category.  so the result would look like

```
catid   itemcount
-------------------
1           3
2           2
3           2

SELECT catid, COUNT(*) AS 'itemcount' FROM allwidgets
 WHERE title like '%widget%' GROUP BY catid;
```

I need to alter this. I want to end up with a list that shows how many are in category 3 and how many are in all other categories so the result would be

```
catid   itemcount
------------------
3           2
allothers   5
```

I could do it with 2 queries, one to get the full count and another to get catid 3 count, then subtract them,  but is it possible with one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN catid = 3 THEN '3' ELSE 'allothers' END AS catid,COUNT(*) AS itemcount 
FROM allwidgets
WHERE title like '%widget%' 
GROUP BY CASE WHEN catid = 3 THEN '3' ELSE 'allothers' END;
```

Comment: Looks good. But you should use single quotes for string literals only. You can make this a mere `AS itemcount`.